# How to proxy/stream HTTPS request using Express/got?

Tags: node.js, express

I’m trying to proxy GitHub user avatars through my server using [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

Without `rejectUnauthorized: false`, the following code block returns error:

> GotError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host:
>   localhost. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:www.github.com,
>   DNS:*.github.com, DNS:github.com, DNS:*.github.io, DNS:github.io,
>   DNS:*.githubusercontent.com, DNS:githubusercontent.com

With `rejectUnauthorized: false`, it returns error:

> HTTPError: Response code 404 (Not Found)

What am I doing wrong?

```js
const server = express()
server.get("/api/github/:username", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.params.username) {
    res.sendStatus(400)
  } else {
    try {
      const stream = got.stream(
        `https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/${req.params.username}?size=64`,
        {
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
        }
      )
      stream.on("error", error => {
        res.sendStatus(500)
      })
      req.pipe(stream).pipe(res)
    } catch (error) {
      res.sendStatus(400)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Once I had the same problem with axios, the solution was to specify the host in the config object, in your case would be 'avatars.githubusercontent.com'

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just tried adding `host` or `hostname` and same errors occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `get` vs `stream` and it works.

That being said, I believe streaming is more efficient so please submit feedback if you know how to achieve the same result using `stream`.

```js
server.get("/api/github/:username", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.params.username) {
    res.sendStatus(400)
  } else {
    try {
      const response = await got(
        `https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/${req.params.username}`,
        { responseType: "buffer" }
      )
      res.set({
        "Content-Length": response.headers["content-length"],
        "Content-Type": response.headers["content-type"],
      })
      res.send(response.body)
    } catch (error) {
      res.sendStatus(500)
    }
  }
})
```